# Make [health-and-safety] a synonym of [safety]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[safety](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) - 312 questions (appears canonical since [dangerous] is a synonym)

[health-and-safety](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-and-safety) - 57 questions

I can't see any reason why these should remain as separate tags. Something unsafe is, by definition, unhealthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. I saw a few questions that used both, and nothing that stands out needing only a single tag. I've approved your proposed synonym. This can still be undone if others have a reason to disagree.